# Django Custom Widget For ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

Does anyone know of a widget that displays 2 select boxes.  One shows a list of all object in a model and the other shows the objects which have been selected.  The user can then select an object from the first list, click an >> button which moves it to the 'selected' list.  Then when the form is saved the objects in the selected list are saved in the manytomany field.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple